# Bootstrap modal: Send modal data to the parent page in the form of list django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, bootstrap-modal

I am working with django templates, there is a part where I have a modal which has various textboxes in the form of a table. I need to send the data from parent web page to next web page in the form of a python list and display the data on parent page in a systematic form like table. Presently i get data to parent page using:

```
$('#save-button').text()
```

using text(), the data I get is:

```
                Capacity
                23
               extra Capacity
                34 
               threshold
                44
```

The modal is as:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="Firstmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add values</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
          <div id="table" class="table-editable">
   <table class="table table-striped" id="tblone">
            <thead id="tblHead">
              <tr>
                <th>Parameters</th>
                <th>Add values</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="onetbl">
            <tr><td>Capacity</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>extra Capacity</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td></tr>
               <tr><td>threshold</td>
                <td contenteditable="true"></td> </tr>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
  <button id="btnSave-one" onClick="reply_click(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>

          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

How can i convert the data from modal to list, so that i can pass to next web page and display on parent page as a table as well? Thanks.

Comment: It's based on a model ? Do you use `ModelForm` for your form ?